# Observed performance degradation with increasing concurrency

Tags: spring-boot, performance, optimization, performance-testing, amazon-efs

I am facing performance issues with my Spring boot application; when I increase the concurrency the performance degrades, and I start getting 10 times slower responses. I am using EFS for some file processing. In my analysis, I am of the impression that accessing EFS files takes significant amount of time when I increase the number of users. Is there any way to improve the EFS performance with increased concurrency?

I have tried by changing the EFS provisioned throughput to burst mode but couldn't observe any significant performance improvement.

I would really appreciate any advice/suggestion/experience inline with this scenarios.

Comment: Have you tried increasing concurrency (more threads, CPUs, more file system requests in parallel, etc); or are you increasing the load (more users) without increasing concurrency (and slamming into some kind of CPU/IO bandwidth limit because there isn't enough concurrency)?

Comment: @Brendan I have increased both load (no. Of users) as well as concurrency (no of threads).I checked the CPU/IO memory used in Jprofile, it is even less than 30% of available memory space.